# Fetching a line which comes 2 lines after searched line from a text file in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

### Text file contains below data:

[image]

```
InitialSearch='Searched data'

file = open("textfile.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

fileOutput = open ('NewTextFile.txt', 'w')

for x,line in enumerate(lines):
    if line.find(InitialSearch)>=0:
        fileOutput.write(line)
fileOutput.close
```

[image]

Code is not properly working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have the `index` of the "matched" line in your for loop. Just add two to it, and you will have the row you want to add to the output file.

```
InitialSearch='Searched data'

file = open("textfile.txt","r")
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

with open('NewTextFile.txt', 'w') as fileOutput
    for x,line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.find(InitialSearch)>=0:
            fileOutput.write(lines[x+2])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Hampus Larsson

Comment: @Gurpreet No problems dude. If it solved your problem, please mark the question as answered.